# "Failed to get sas uri for file" Error When Deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an ASP.NET website that I packaged in VS.NET and tried to upload in portal.azure.com.  When I tried to upload either the package or the .cscfg file, I get this error:

```
Failed to get sas uri for file, storage account id was: 
/subscriptions/0fe274df-e7ea-404a-be09-eca2220e82fb/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/usstpprod,
 and file name was: fce5fcd9-7958-4e31-9b36-c24a8d247da7.cscfg,
Reason: message: Unexpected error for account '/subscriptions/0fe274df-e7ea-404a-be09-eca2220e82fb/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/usstpprod':
 reason errorThrown: jqXHR: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Per my understanding, you could follow the steps below to isolate this issue. 1) Create a new classic storage, then update your deployment on portal.azure.com; 2) Try to access manage.windowsazure.com to update your deployment; 3) Directly publish your cloud service via visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same exact steps again today and got it to work.  Weird as nothing has changed as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. Then tried using classic storage account. Firstly I have used the location of storage as southeast Asia then file not got uploaded. and got the same error. But as I change the storage to south India and it worked and uploaded successfully. So might be Location is the problem.
[image]